# ISO/IEC 7816 commands over CCID

Tags: usb, smartcard, icc, smartcard-reader, iccid

I'm currently discovering the smart card world and there are some things that I don't understand.
I'm developing a driver that talks to my smart card reader (USB) using the CCID protocol (I succeeded in having basic communications).

But then if I want to talk to my card using ISO/IEC 7816-4 specification, I will keep using the CCID protocol and in the PC_to_RDR_XfrBlock() request, in the data part (abData at offset 10 cf $6.1.4 page 30 specification of [CCID](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/DWG_Smart-Card_CCID_Rev110.pdf)) I will directly send my ISO/IEC 7816 command as READ_BINARY, WRITE_BINARY, SELECT ... And the smartcard reader will answer me using RDR_to_PC_DataBlock() ($6.2.1 page 49).

This question is OS independent, and not using any existing drivers or OS library.

Am I right?

Comment: To prevent future disappointment: ISO 7816-4 is a **standard** not a *specification*; this especially means, that you can't rely of practically any feature to be really implemented from the token or card in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found my answer by analysing trames with wireshark. It seems to work as I described it.

Here are somes links that will help user that tries to do the same.

To setup usb capture :
https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB

To enable iso 7816 frames analysis in wireshark (inside ccid packets): https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/32594/iso-7816-example-capture

Comment: Thanks for the usefull links on wireshark and CCID spec.